# flutter build only a single widget

Tags: flutter

I have two widgets in a column. One is Text and second is TextButton. What i want that if i click on button then the Text widget rebuild only not the whole page.

I am new to flutter how can i achieve this? If i convert this to a statful widget and call setState method then whole page will be rebuild. but i want to know any trick to do rebuild only a single widget out of whole page.

```
class Page3 extends StatelessWidget {
  Color color = Colors.red;

  changeColor() {
    // do something to rebuild only 1st column Text not the whole page
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Page3'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            //First widget
            Text(
              'Title',
              style: TextStyle(color: color),
            ),
            //Second widget
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => changeColor(),
              child: Text('change color of title'),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Separate out the child components of column i.e. text and button components as one stateful component, then when you update the state only that component will re-render.

Comment: @MohitKushwaha i want to know if there any trick without converting my second widget (button) to stateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to below code

`ValueListenableBuilder` widget. It is an amazing widget. It builds the widget every time the valueListenable value changes. Its values remain synced with there listeners i.e. whenever the values change the ValueListenable listen to it. It updates the UI without using `setState()` or any other `state management technique`.

In Dart, a `ValueNotifier` is a special type of class that extends a ChangeNotifer . ... It can be an int , a String , a bool or your own data type. Using a ValueNotifier improves the performance of Flutter app as it can help to reduce the number times a widget gets rebuilt.

`ValueListenableBuilder` will listen for changes to a value notifier and automatically rebuild its children when the value changes.

For more info refer to this [link description](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/exploring-valuelistenablebuilder-in-flutter-9a16fc4c4c5b)

Solution 1

```
class Page3 extends StatelessWidget {
  Color color = Colors.red;
  final ValueNotifier<bool> updateColor = ValueNotifier(false);

  changeColor(Color changedColor) {
    // do something to rebuild only 1st column Text not the whole page
    color = changedColor;
    updateColor.value = !updateColor.value;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Page3'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            //First widget
            ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
                valueListenable: updateColor,
                builder: (context, val, child) {
                  return Text(
                    'Title',
                    style: TextStyle(color: color),
                  );
                }),
            //Second widget
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => changeColor(Colors.purple),
              child: Text('change color of title'),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Solution 2

In `ValueListenable` we pass our created `ValueNotifier` variable whose changes will be notified and in builder we will return a widget that will be reflected every time when the value of `ValueNotifier` will be changed.

```
class Page3 extends StatelessWidget {
  // Color color = Colors.red;
  final ValueNotifier<Color> updateColor = ValueNotifier(Colors.red);

  changeColor(Color changedColor) {
    // do something to rebuild only 1st column Text not the whole page
    updateColor.value = changedColor;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Page3'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            //First widget
            ValueListenableBuilder<Color>(
                valueListenable: updateColor,
                builder: (context, val, child) {
                  return Text(
                    'Title',
                    style: TextStyle(color: val),
                  );
                }),
            //Second widget
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => changeColor(Colors.purple),
              child: Text('change color of title'),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: I could easily change the color by  creating my class statefull . Even i know about providers . But i wanted another trick and you understood my problem and thanks it working as i want.

Comment: Always happy to help. Please check Solution 2 also.

Comment: You can choose either of the solutions, both works same

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code of what you need to do

```
class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  const Demo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Demo> createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {

var isTextChanged = false;

Void changeColor() {
setState(() {
  isTextChanged = true;
});
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Page3'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            //First widget
            Text(
              'Title',
              style: TextStyle(color: isTextChanged ? Colors.red : Colors.black),
            ),
            //Second widget
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => changeColor(),
              child: Text('change color of title'),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: is not the the AppBar and TextButton would rebuild by this approach?

Comment: No nothing rebuilds only text color will be changed by this code.

Comment: As i know calling setState will trigger rebuild the entire build method and child widgets. i think you misunderstood my question.

Comment: No that's not true it just changes value of the state variable and then auto reflects the changes in UI.

Comment: Please approve answer because it is a working code.

Comment: refer the answer i accepted.  That is what i wanted without converting my class to statefulwidget.

Comment: Calling setState will trigger the build method "rebuilding" everything in the stated widget, you're correct @Curious. That said, that doesn't mean it will be redrawn. Flutter uses 2 widget trees and is smart enough.

Answer (score 0):

`setState`function can not be called inside `StatelessWidget` widget. if you want to rebuild the widget tree, you have to convert it to `StatefulWidget`.

This is what you can do.

```
class Page3 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page3();

  @override
  _Page3State createState() => _Page3State();
}

class _Page3State extends State<Page3> {

  Color color = Colors.red;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [
        Text(
          'Title',
          style: TextStyle(color: color),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () => changeColor(),
          child: Text('change color of title'),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }

  changeColor() {
    setState(() {
      color = Colors.green;
    });
  }
}
```

If you want to rebuild the `Text` widget without rebuilding the whole `Page3` then you need to got for 'state management' solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how setState works.
Lets assume you have a class named `HomeScreen`, within the homescreen you are overriding the `build` method to build your own widgets.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Column(
    children:<Widget> [
      FirstTextWidget();
      SecondTextWidget();
      ThirdTextWidget(),
    ])
}
```

when you call SetState function within that "homesceeen" class, the homescreen class itself calls the `build` method again and all of componenets you have returned within build function get re-rendered. Every text within homescreen class gets rerendered.
So whats the solution?
The Solution is separate your stateful widget with different class so that only those widgets gets rerendered when needed not whole. I will prefer you to use State Management plugin like Provider, bloc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you. you must used `StateFulWidget` for that

Create one bool variable

```
bool isButtonPressed = true;
```

Your widgets:

```
     Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Title',
                    style: isButtonPressed
                        ? TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 20,
                          )
                        : TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  child: new Text('Change color'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isButtonPressed = !isButtonPressed;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Your Screen without button pressed: [image]

Your Screen with button pressed:[image]